# val() on textarea stops working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dom, textarea

I have a website/tablet html5 web app where I use textareas.

My problem is that "some" javascript code/library or whatever makes the val() call on the textarea malfunction. It always returns the value that you normally get with text() - the text set from server side. I use ton of jquery on this web app without any problems.

First thing I made sure is that the DOM itself is correct without any problems. I saved the whole DOM to a new html file and removed all javascripts. With a simple button I'm able to read the textarea with val().

The same reading code executed in the real website will malfunction though. SO there is kind of a dependency with the other existing javascript codes/libraries.

The server side architecture is an ASP.Net website. Therefore there is quite some code running in the background (Scriptmanager, MS Ajax, Third Party controls, ....)

The website uses jQuery 1.4.2. I've tried overloading a local jQuery version 1.9.1 just for that tiny val() part with noConflict() to exclude any old version issues with no luck.

I know I'm VERY abstract but due to the fact that the website is dependet on a huge database and all the development is inside a closed network I can provide a link.

Is anybody aware of "disturbing" influences on the jQuery functionality espiecially with val()?

Thank you

Comment: It's hard to say without mentioning the other libraries used or anything else that's affecting the `textarea`... if I had to guess I would say you're using some kind of javascript rich text editor like TinyMCE which has it's own API to get/set values.

Comment: Hi ahren, TinyMCE is not used. But I use the Syncfusion ASP.Net controls framework. The textarea controls mentioned in my post are pure ASP/HTML textareas though.

Comment: The value of a [`<textarea>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/HTML_Elements/textarea) element is technically the character data inside of the element, which happens to also be what `.text()` returns. Am I misunderstanding the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/Gn4wk/1/

Comment: Hi Ruben, thanks. No, the text() will deliver the original text set from the server side. The val() function will give you the new text which might have been changed by the user. Actually the "new" value is not visible e.g. in FireBug. It's hidden "somewhere" else.

Comment: @MatthiasMax Ah, that makes more sense. You are correct, assuming you are setting the new value from the server by using `.val('some text string')`. There are ways to make that not be the case, however, like setting the value with `.text('some text string')` ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/Gn4wk/2/)). Without any code from your end, that is probably all the help I can provide.

Comment: Make sure you're assigning new value to the correct textarea and also check whether there are any errors in console. After setting value on client side, if postback occurs, you'll loose the data set on client side.

Comment: Nil, the app doesnt you postbacks. It's all AJAX. No console errors. The behavious is totally mystic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: I had build a complex structure of setTimeouts and timers (due to the lack of a real "close keyboard" event on tablets/phones). This led to bein unable to read my val() of the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can try writing a generic method like below or use .attr('value') if the control is a text area.

```
var m = this.val();  
return (m == "" ? this.attr('value') : m);
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks very much for all the input. It seems impossible to find the real reason for the malfunction of val() in this case.

My workaround now is to set the .text() on every keypress() event of the textarea. Thats the only way I can get the newly entered text of the user out of the box later on.

I'm using a secong control (hidden) to store my original default text of the box to be able to restore to this. The whole app is full on AJAX (almost like an off line app).

Thanks anyone!